# Jooq casting String to BigDecimal

Tags: java, casting, precision, bigdecimal, jooq

Is there a way to cast a String to a BigDecimal in a jooq-query without losing precision?

When i do *endResER.VALUE.cast(BigDecimal.class)* where *VALUE* is a field with a String-value in the database it returns a BigDecimal without any fraction digits.

I need to compare two amounts that are saved as Strings in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your value to a SQLDataType like this:

```
endResER.VALUE.cast(SQLDataType.DECIMAL.precision(10, 5))
```

Beware though, that there is a known issue for jOOQ 3.1: [#2708](http://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2708).