# jooq - select removes varchar length information of cast

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, varchar, jooq

when call this code

```
DSLContext dslContext = DSL.using(SQLDialect.SQLSERVER);
dslContext.select(DSL.cast(field, SQLDataType.VARCHAR.length(255)));
```

the select statement removes the information of the varchar length. 
The DSL.cast() method returns `cast("fieldName" as varchar(255))` and the select returns `select cast("fieldName" as varchar)`.

The problem ist that in SQLServer the cast without length information cuts the result after 30 characters which is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187928.aspx). This is very anoying because my values are more than 30 characters long. So has anybody an idee how I can get a select statement which looks like this `select cast("fieldName" as varchar(255))`?

Comment: What jOOQ version are you using?

Comment: I am using jooq-codegen-maven 3.0.0.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401667/jooq-casting-string-to-bigdecimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Length, precision, and scale information on [`DataType`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DataType.html) were introduced only in jOOQ 3.0, although that information was not used in `CAST()` expressions until jOOQ 3.2 ([issue #2708](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2708)):

The latest version of jOOQ correctly renders

```
cast([fieldName] as varchar(255))
```

So, I suggest upgrading to the latest version.

Besides, if your version / usage generate `cast("fieldName" as varchar)`, I suspect you might also be passing the wrong `SQLDialect` (instead of `SQLSERVER`). With the `SQLSERVER` dialect, identifiers are generated using `[brackets]`, unlike other dialects that use `"double quotes"` for identifiers...

Comment: Thanks. You are right this is the syntax for SQLServer uses brackets. I´ve tried different dialects - which all behave the same - so I mixed up the example.

Comment: @Simone: OK, just wanted to be sure about the dialect :) So did upgrading work for you?

Comment: Yes. By the way how does cast expressions behave in concat expressions, if the field has a varchar with length? Something like this <code>DSL.concat(DELIM, table.val)</code>

Comment: @Simone: Hmm, where is the cast in that example? btw: you can use back-ticks like ` ``code`` ` to delimit code on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Something like this Field<String> DELIM = inline("\""); DSL.concat(DELIM, table.val, DELIM); where table.val is of type VARCHAR(4000)? Is table.val cast because it is of type VARCHAR(4000) and not of type VARCHAR?

Comment: @Simone: No, there should be no automatic cast because of `DSL.concat()` when using it this way... There may be casts when you pass non-String values to `concat()`, though. Did you encounter any particular issue?

Comment: I´ve tried it with version 3.0.0. and table.val is casted. Do not know how it behaves in newer versions.